JdbcPagingItemReader is missing to read few records when used with SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor
I am trying to read from table and dump the data in file
My job configuration looks like this
Task executor -->
   @Bean
    public TaskExecutor tvlTaskExecutor() {

        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(5);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }

Step config -->
@Bean
public Step tvlFileCreationStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
    return new StepBuilder("tvl-file-creation-step", jobRepository)
            .<String, String>chunk(50, transactionManager)
            .reader(tvlTableDataItemReader())
            .writer(tvlFileWriter)
            .listener(tvlStepExecutionListener)
            .taskExecutor(tvlTaskExecutor())
            .build();
}

job config -->
@Bean(name="tvlRunJob")
public Job tvlRunJob( JobRepository jobRepository,  Step tvlFileCreationStep) {
    return new JobBuilder("tvlFileCreationJob", jobRepository)
            .start(tvlFileCreationStep)
            .build();

}

and finally the reader -->
public JdbcPagingItemReader<String> jdbcPagingItemReader(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {

    // reading ITAG keys records using JDBC in a paging fashion
    JdbcPagingItemReader<String> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<String>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setPageSize(50);
    reader.setSaveState(true);
    reader.setQueryProvider(createQuery(dataSource));
    reader.setRowMapper(new TVLRowMapper());
    return reader;



}

private PagingQueryProvider createQuery(DataSource dataSource) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("TAG_SERIAL_NUMBER", Order.ASCENDING);

    final SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider = new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    queryProvider.setDataSource(dataSource);
    queryProvider.setSelectClause(" TAG_SERIAL_NUMBER ");
    queryProvider.setFromClause(" ITAGENTITY_10052024 ");
    queryProvider.setWhereClause(" TAG_SERIAL_NUMBER like '09900%' ");
    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    return queryProvider.getObject();
}

My writer config looks like -->
using XMLOutputFactory2 - from the stax2
and using XMLStreamWriter2 as writer - from stax2 implementaion 
which is thread safe as per documentation 
package path - org.codehaus.stax2.*;

When i use single threaded approach - it reads all records , but when i use taskExecutor - it is missing out on few records , it is missing 4-5 records out of 700 records
( Note - actual volume is huge - So i need to implement multi threaded approach .)
Please let me know if i have done anything incorrect or wrong.
Any help is appreciated , thank you

I doubt it is the reader, writing concurrently to a file simply won't work, there will be situations you have where each writer instance points to the same place in the file, overwriting each others changes (or it might even get worse).

It was a very silly miss, JdbcPagingItemReader - when working with Async task executor - we can not use state.
I was using SimpleAsyncTask - it will just randomize the chunks and send them to writer , so my writer was fine. I was getting some records extra some time and some records less some time
So for Async just make sure you set the saveState to false
 JdbcPagingItemReader<String> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<String>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setPageSize(50);
    // change the below line  
    reader.setSaveState(false);
    reader.setQueryProvider(createQuery(dataSource));
    reader.setRowMapper(new TVLRowMapper());
    return reader;

